# How do I correctly apply patterns to function arguments using Pattern (:), PatternTest (?), and Condition (/;)

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Given:

```
Clear[func];
listOfLists = {{a, b}, {c, d, e}};
listOfRules = {a -> b, c -> d};
```

I can discern between listOfLists and listOfRules using MatchQ:

```
MatchQ[listOfLists, {__List ..}] (*True*)
MatchQ[listOfLists, {__Rule ..}] (*False*)
MatchQ[listOfRules, {__Rule ..}] (*True*)
MatchQ[listOfRules, {__List ..}] (*False*)
```

But, my function definitions don't discern between these two cases:

```
Clear[func]
func[x_ : {__List ..}] := "The argument was a list of lists"
func[x_ : {__Rule ..}] := "The argument was a list of rules"
```

where:

```
func[listOfLists] (*returns "The argument was a list of rules"*)
func[listOfRules] (*returns "The argument was a list of rules"*)
```

Why doesn't this work?

How would you have implemented this?

Can you clarify when you would use the various pattern syntaxes:
"name:patt", versus "patt/;test", versus "patt?test".

Comment: The question and answer is rather pedagogical. Perhaps the title should highlight the points addressed to increase the chances of it being found by future users. Maybe something like  " Clarifying the similar syntax of Pattern and Optional and ways to use conditions on patterns"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is somewhat subtle, but really it's just a syntax issue. If you want to use the colon for pattern-matching, leave off the underscore, i.e.,

```
Clear[func]
func[x : {__List ..}] := "The argument was a list of lists"
func[x : {__Rule ..}] := "The argument was a list of rules"
```

Then these work correctly:

```
func[listOfLists]
func[listOfRules]
(* "The argument was a list of lists" *)
(* "The argument was a list of rules" *)
```

The issue is that `x_` already stands for the pattern, and so doing `x_ : patt` doesn't really perform any sort of matching.  However, using the syntax `x : patt`, then `x` *names* the pattern, and you can use it in later expressions.  To be clear, under the definitions of these functions as given, you don't even need the `x`.  That is,

```
func[{__List ..}] := "The argument was a list of lists"
func[{__Rule ..}] := "The argument was a list of rules"
```

work just like the above version with the `x : patt`.  However, if you want to *use* the value of the input in the body of the function, then you need to name the pattern.  For instance,

```
Clear[func]
func[x : {__List ..}] := x^2
func[x : {__Rule ..}] := {a, b^2, c^3, d^4} /. x
(* {{a^2, b^2}, {c^2, d^2, e^2}} *)
(* {b, b^2, d^3, d^4} *)
```

Finally, note that we can simplify the patterns `{__List ..}` and `{__Rule ..}` to just `{__List}` and `{__Rule}`, because the double-underscore (`BlankSequence`) automatically matches one or more objects, so `{__List}` will match any list of one or more `List`s.

---

This in my opinion is the cleanest way of doing this, but there are alternatives.  The following patterns using `/;` and `?` also work.  First, using `?`, we have

```
func[x_?(MatchQ[#, {__List}] &)] := ...
func[x_?(MatchQ[#, {__Rule}] &)] := ...
```

or the more succinct

```
func[x_?(MatchQ[{__List}])] := ...
func[x_?(MatchQ[{__Rule}])] := ...
```

the latter of which takes advantage of the operator form of `MatchQ` (unfortunately, the parentheses are still required for strange precedence reasons).  The `?` notation means that the pattern will match provided the function following `?` evaluates to `True` when applied to `x`.

Using `/;`, we have

```
func[x_ /; MatchQ[x, {__List}]] := ...
func[x_ /; MatchQ[x, {__Rule}]] := ...
```

The `/;` has a slightly more general functionality than `?`, because `x_` will match any pattern so long as what follows the `/;` evaluates to `True`, and what follows `/;` does *not* have to be applied to `x` (although it usually is). For instance,

```
gg[x_ /; True]
```

is essentially the same as just `gg[x_]`. In addition `/;` can be used inside or outside the arguments of the function or even on the right-hand side of the entire expression, i.e.,

```
hh[x_ /; x > 2] := ...
hh[x_] /; x > 2 := ...
hh[x_] := ...  /; x > 2
```

all essentially do the same thing.

We  usually prefer `/;` over `?` when doing things like logical tests:

```
g[x_ /; x > 2] := ...
```

is nicer than

```
g[x_?(# > 2 &)] := ...
```

---

Finally, just a little bit of syntax notes. `Optional` and `Pattern` have very similar syntax, because they both use a colon `:`. You can tell the difference partly in the way that they are used, but the syntax coloring also gives it away. Compare the following two code snippets:

```
f[x_: "a"] := x+1
g[x : "a"] := x+1
```

and consider the following sequence of commands:

```
f[b]      (* 1 + b *)
f["a"]    (* 1 + "a" *)
f[]       (* 1 + "a" *)
g[b]      (* g[b] *)
g["a"]    (* 1 + "a" *)
g[]       (* g[] *)
```

The `x_: default` notation allows you to specify a *default* value for the function that will be returned if you provide no input. Otherwise, it will evaluate the function on whatever you're feeding to it.  On the other hand, the `x : patt` notation makes it so that the function `g` will only evaluate if the input `x` matches `patt`, which in this case means that it returns unevaluated (e.g., `g[b]` returns `g[b]`) unless `x` is exactly `"a"`.

Comment: In addition, the combination of __ and .. is unnecessarily complex. One could just use `MatchQ[listOfLists, {__List}]` and `func[x : {__List}] := "The argument was a list of lists"` (and similiarly for the others).

Comment: @lericr Ah true! Didn't really pay attention to that part. I'm going to go ahead and add that.

Comment: @march, Thank you! I originally had {_List..}, and then realized I could use {__List} and forgot to remove the "..". I'll keep the mistake in my answer so others can learn from it. Would you mind adding a couple of alternative ways to accomplish the same thing using patt/;test and patt?test? Finally, I confused the syntax for Pattern[] with the syntax for Optional[] arguments. Both are represented with a ":"!

Comment: @tjm167us I added a little extra stuff.

Comment: @march very nice clear pedagogical answer. There might be a typo where it should be `g[x : "a"] := x + 1` instead of `f[x : "a"] := x + 1`

Comment: @userrandrand You are correct.  I have fixed it!

Comment: nice. It was a rather nice read +1.

Comment: @march, well done - very helpful!